# Failing to create a Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a model in my database using this command :`npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name Task --attributes task:string` but I keep getting this error:`ERROR: Unable to find models path (/Users/andela/Desktop/to_do_list/models). Did you run sequelize init?` and of course yes-I already run sequelize init and I even have the folder in my project.

Here is my sequelizerc folder:[sequelizerc-folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzQCh.png)

Comment: So there's a folder (not a file) at exactly the path `/Users/andela/Desktop/to_do_list/models` ?

Comment: Show your `.sequelizerc`